# postgresql crosstab simple example

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I got a key-value based table where each key-value pair is assigned to an entity which is identified by an id:

```
| id  | key       | value |
|-----|-----------|-------|
| 123 | FIRSTNAME | John  |
| 123 | LASTNAME  | Doe   |
```

And I want to transform it a structure like this:

```
| id  | firstName | lastName |
|-----|-----------|----------|
| 123 | John      | Doe      |
```

I suppose one can use postgres built-in `crosstab` function to do it.

**Can you show me how to do it and explain why it works?**

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002499/808723 example which is slighly different.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all activate the build in `tablefunc`-extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Then create table and add sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id int,
  key text,
  value text
);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
  (123, 'firstName', 'John'),
  (123, 'lastName', 'Doe');
```

Now lets prepare the `crosstab` statment:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
ORDER BY id ASC, key ASC;
```

Its important to have the `ORDER BY` here.

Result:

```
|_id__|_key_______|_value_|
| 123 | FIRSTNAME | John  |
| 123 | LASTNAME  | Doe   |
```

---

### Solution

Now `crosstab` creates the table as we want:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT *
     FROM example
     ORDER BY id ASC, key ASC;'
) AS ct(id INT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT);
```

Result:

```
|_id__|_firstName_|_lastName_|
| 123 | John      | Doe      |
```

---

### How it works #1

To however understand how it works I found it easiest to just change the `ORDER BY` and see what happens:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT *
     FROM example
     ORDER BY id ASC, key DESC;'
) AS ct(id INT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT);
```

Result:

```
|_id__|_firstName_|_lastName_|
| 123 | Doe       | John     |
```

As we changed the sorting of the key, the `crosstab` function sees the keys sorted in the other direction, thus reversing the generated columns.

---

### How it works #2

Another thing that helped me understand how it works: the column definition is all about positions:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT *
     FROM example
     ORDER BY id ASC, key ASC;'
) AS ct(blablafirst INT, blablasecond TEXT, blablathird TEXT);
```

Result

```
|_blablafirst__|_blablasecond_|_blablathird_|
| 123          | John         | Doe         |
```

Comment: Also see this explanation that I found helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/808723

Comment: Doesn't the last query(`How it works #2`) should resulting in `John` under the `_blablasecond_` because of you used `key ASC`?

Comment: @yshahak yeah, right. I have updated the example. Thanks.

Comment: What if you don't know ahead of time what the "keys" are? Is there a way to make the resulting column list dynamic(ally sized)?

Comment: @cloudsurfin please open a new question for that.