# SQL | Select rows as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table schema as below:

| Student ID | Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths | 10 |
| 1 | Physics | 30 |
| 2 | Maths | 25 |

I want to select the values in below format:

| Student ID | Maths | Physics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | 25 |  |

Could you please suggest how this can be accomplished in SQL? I'm using Postgresql.

Or I'll have to do it in Java as that is our middleware?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` function which belongs to the [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) module.
First, download the module.

After you can use this query (*necessary inserts can be found [here](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zapyx9yz)*):

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'select student_id, subject, mark::text 
     from student_marks
     order by student_id ASC, mark ASC'
) AS ct(entity_id integer, "Math" text, "Physics" text);
```

Here `crosstab` receives 1 argument, a SQL query as a text, and transposes the query's result into these columns: `entity_id`, `Math` and `Physics`.

You can find out more about the `crosstab` here: **[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/20666497)**, **[two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051960/20666497)**.